# How I can select workitems with specific changes in history in last some days?

Tags: tfs, wiql

I want to select only workitems which have been changed with some specific comments in last 14 days.
Something like this:

```
SELECT     [System.Id]
FROM workitems
WHERE [System.History] CONTAINS WORDS 'Tyry-pyry'
ASOF @today - 14
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

We do not have this kind of operate with editor date for a specific filed such as `system.history`.

There is no such build-in feature from a query or wiql.

You may have to first use query `[System.History] CONTAINS WORDS 'Tyry-pyry'` to list all work items which history contain such word.

Then use Rest API to query all above work item's detail history information. Use conditional statements or export them in excel to filter time of the comment which contain word "Tyry-pyry" added in 14 days.

Comment: It bring me all workitems that contain words 'Tyry-pyry' and was created in last 30 days. 
I need select those of them which been added 'Tyry-pyry' in last 14 days, for example. But in the same time that workitems could be created anytime. Last month, Last year. It doesn't metter

Comment: Hi @axtrace Ok I get your point. Sorry for the misunderstanding, have updated reply. This is not available at present. We  do not have such kind of date operate for a field change time. You may use Rest API to achieve this. Details please see my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can go in queries -> new
and make a filter like this

Comment: it select the whole. If there was some string somewhere. I need more specific thing: if some string was added in history during the last two weeks, for example. No earlier